# How to convert floating number to string array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to convert a floating number to a string array, for example `var num=25.67` into `var str_array[0] = '2', str_array[1]='5', str_array[2]='.', str[3]='6'; str_array[4]='7'` .
Please show your code.  Thank you very in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy. You just have to convert the `num` var into an string (with the `.toString()` method) and then `.split('')` it (the '' parameter makes it split every character).

```
var num = 25.67;
var str_array = num.toString().split('');
```

You can also use this code:

```
var num = 25.67;
var str_array = num.toString();
```

Then `str_array` will be no more an array, but a string (which can be treated as an array)

Comment: "Treated as an array" - No, a string does not inherit methods from `Array.prototype`. Though it does have numeric keys which act like [`.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Comment: What I mean is that you can access a character from a string using square brackets like you do when you wanna access an item of an array

Comment: Thank you.  Really aprreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
var digits = num.toString().split('');
```